# Unable to execute Quartz Simple Trigger Tutorial

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Hi i have tried for two days to run this code example from Quartz Scheduler simple trigger.
This example show a code to run a schedule job for every two days but my compiler return error

Tutorial site http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/BiDailyTrigger

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder //error: non-static method withIdentity(String,String) cannot be referenced from a static
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
            .startAt(tomorrowAt(15, 0, 0)
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()   //error:cannot find  symbol:   method withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder)
            .withIntervalInHours(2 * 24) // interval is actually set at 48    hours' worth of milliseconds
            .repeatForever())
            .build());
```

is there any of good folk here can help me point out what is my mistake. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: i am using quartz jar library version 2.2.1.

if this help i run this code from main(String[] args)

Comment: have anybody tried the tutorial?, i have followed all the instruction but still have error. maybe this is just a newbie mistake and i am hoping for experience people to guide me on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you linked to uses `newTrigger()` but you are using `TriggerBuilder`.  `newTrigger()` is a static method on `TriggerBuilder` - use it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, your error with .withSchedule is because the quartz example has a missing ")" before that method. If you add that it will get rid of that method error.